# Liveness check Android (Blink eye)

Tags: android, detection

Since Android 4.0 Google has provided some face detection APIs.

In Jelly Bean we can see a "Liveness check" feature in FaceUnlock.

I have searched a lot in Google and I haven't found a way to implement this. I mean, capture user's blink of an eye.

I have seen some OpenCV threads but since Android already supplies this, I guess there's no need to use any other API.

So, can anyone help me on how to create a "Liveness check" feature using just plain Android APIs?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I am also looking for something similar but not finding any solution.